# How to add a plugin to CouchDB

Tags: erlang, couchdb, erlang-otp, erl

I need to install plugin to CouchDB. The problem is that the only folder I can access on the server is user home directory. 
After I set ERL_LIBS env variable I can call my plugin module from erl console, but CouchDB returns '{"error":"unknown_error","reason":"undef"}'.

What is the right way to include external libraries on CouchDB start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to add an erlang module using the couchdb shell. Here is what I did:

1. I  started couchdb in interactive mode `sudo couchdb -i`
2. Added the path to the beginning of the list with `code:add_patha("/home/akshat/Desktop").`
3. Tested the list of paths with `code:get_path().`
4. Found my path as the first item
5. Compiled the module with `c("/home/akshat/Desktop/test").`
6. Loaded the module with `code:load_file(test).`
7. Called the module `test:test()`

To test if the module is loaded by couchdb automatically on start you can restart couchdb and call a function within the module without performing the steps above. It should work as expected.

This is the module I used for testing purposes

```
-module(test).
-export([test/0]).

test()->
    hello.
```

I think the problem with what you did could be that you did not add the module using the couchdb shell.